# many-to-many and one-to-many relationship in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

There are three table
table 1 and table 2 has many-to-many relationship.
so used set<> while mapping in .hbm.xml in both files and made a many-to-many relationship.
Now,table 2 and table 3 has one to many relationship
so,do I have to use set again in table_2.hbm.xml?

Answer (score 0):

On `One` side you should use Set. On `Many` side just a reference to other entity.